# All Cordova pages showing on index page not able navigate

Tags: cordova, mobile, jquery-mobile

I'm new to mobile development with Cordova. I'm trying to find my way around with a project I created but I ran into a two problems. First issue, I'm using Jquery mobile for UI controls but my buttons and UI elements are not being rendered how it should I made sure that my dependency scripts and style sheets are reference as well in the right order(see code below). Secondly I have two pages, "indexpage" and "formspage" the problem I'm experiencing when I launch my app both pages are been rendered on the same view I'm not sure why this is so, see code below. I would greatly appreciate your help.

Link to image:
  https://ibb.co/bEeP1e

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <!--
        Customize the content security policy in the meta tag below as needed. Add 'unsafe-inline' to default-src to enable inline JavaScript.
        For details, see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=617521
    -->
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Security-Policy" content="default-src 'self' data: gap: https://ssl.gstatic.com 'unsafe-eval'; style-src 'self' 'unsafe-inline'; media-src *">

    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name="format-detection" content="telephone=no">
    <meta name="msapplication-tap-highlight" content="no">
    <meta name="viewport" content="user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, width=device-width">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    <title>FISApp</title>
</head>
<body>
    <div data-role="page" id="indexpage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>FISApp</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content">
            <a href="#formspage" class="ui-btn">Forms</a>
        </div>
    </div>

    <div data-role="page" id="formspage">
        <div data-role="header">
            <h3>Forms</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="ui-content">
            <ul data-role="listview">
                <li><a href="#">Acura</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Audi</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">BMW</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Cadillac</a></li>
                <li><a href="#">Ferrari</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery-3.3.1.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="cordova.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/platformOverrides.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/index.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems like I have found the solution for my problem. There seem to be a compatibility issue with the lastest stable versions of Jquery,Jquery Mobile and Jquery UI. So I downgraded to jquery-1.12.4.js,jquery.mobile-1.4.5.min.js,jquery-ui.min.js. and it works referencing and styling etc.